# How to fix "multi-argument returns are not permitted" when making function

Tags: r, function, if-statement, return

To learn how to create functions, I am trying to make one that calculates averages, with three different error codes. However, I get two different error messages when running this code.

If i try `avg(5)`, that is of just one number, I get "argument "no" is missing, with no default". And when trying `avg("f")`, so of something that is not a number I get the error: " multi-argument returns are not permitted"
. 
What I want is for it to state it need several numbers if just one is given, and that the argument must be numerical if a character is given. I do belive the second problem could be solved by some kind of "Halt" commmand, however my (probably horrible) googling hasn't lead me to anything such as that. 
Appreciate all help, and thanks in advance!

```
avg <- function(x){
  ifelse(class(x) == "numeric" & length(x)>1,
         return(sum(x)/length(x)),
         ifelse(class(x)!= "numeric",
                return("Need to be numeric",
                       ifelse(length(x) <= 1,
                              return("Need more than one number"),
                              return("Unknown error")))))

  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just to show you that the problem is your inappropriate use of `ifelse`. It should be only used if you have a condition of length > 1. Otherwise, you should (in this specific case must) use `if` and `else`:

```
avg <- function(x){
  if (class(x) == "numeric" & length(x)>1)
         return(sum(x)/length(x)) else 
           if (class(x)!= "numeric")
                return("Need to be numeric") else 
                  if (length(x) <= 1)
                              return("Need more than one number") else
                              return("Unknown error")

}

avg(5)
#[1] "Need more than one number"
avg("f")
#[1] "Need to be numeric"
avg(c(1.5, 1.6))
#[1] 1.55
```

There are other issues here:

You should not return these messages. Instead you should create an error (using `stop`).

You should use `is.numeric(x)` instead of `class(x) == "numeric"`. The former will be `TRUE` for integers, the latter won't.

The `else` is not actually needed if you `return` or `stop` if the condition is `TRUE`.

Answer (score 0):

Using your code without simplification to have it works as is :

```
avg <- function(x){
  ifelse(
    class(x) == "numeric" & length(x)>1,
    return(sum(x)/length(x)),
    ifelse(
      class(x)!= "numeric",
      return("Need to be numeric"),
      ifelse(length(x) <= 1,
        return("Need more than one number"),
        return("Unknown error")
      )
    )
  )
}

avg(numeric())
avg(1)
avg(c(1, 2))
avg("f")
avg(c(NA, 1))
```

Please have a look at @Roland 's answer to improve code quality.

Comment: Only line breaks, it is exactly the same code. I don't have an explanation sorry.